# Cannot read smarty php class

Tags: php, class, smarty

I have problem with smarty php class.Apache cannot read smarty templates.I put something on bottom of my file with smarty confis and includes and it just shows that text.

How  can i fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: can you please post your index.php where you init the class

Comment: Does it gives you any error? do you have error reporting and display errors on?

Comment: I might be wide of the mark here, ages since I've used smarty but can you confirm these are writable:

$smarty->setTemplateDir('template');
$smarty->setCompileDir('cache/template_c');
$smarty->setCacheDir('cache/other_c');
$smarty->setConfigDir('includes/configs');

Comment: No errors..Error reporting is ON

Comment: Apache has got nothing to do with smarty, since the tpl files are parsed through smarty engine, can you post the output ?

Answer (score -1):

your apache didn't parse php-files :-(

look at your httpd.conf for:

```
// if you run as modul
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

[further informations about php and apache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)